# Chemical theory, formula(s) that predict final *volume* of a solution?

Tags: physical-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solubility, mixtures

I asked [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/23534/9411) question a couple years back regarding the volume of a mixture being less than the volume of the original solute and solvent, but this question asks if there is theory and/or formulation that can predict what the final volume would be. And based on the answers from the last question I suspect there may be more than one answer depending on the nature of constituents (ionic vs molecular solution, etc.)

Furthermore in the case of ionic salts is there a theory/formulation that predict which saturated salt solution (e.g. a chloride, acetate, bromide, etc.) would result in the most efficient packing between water molecules (at the ame temperature).

Does such theory, formulation exist?

Comment: Look at: http://www.thermopedia.com/content/734/
Equations of state can be used to describe the behaviour of single and multi-phase systems to varying degrees of accuracy. I'm not familiar with any work addressing your question about the water packing in a salt solution.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44487/theory-of-volume-contraction-in-solution